# Finding images in Wikipedia that are being used across various articles

Tags: php, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to query wikipedia using MediaWiki api with php (and Curl), in order to search for images that are being used in various articles by a specific search term. For example - search for 'panda', but get only images that are being used somewhere and be able to go to the articles. 
I am able to search for images generally using:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allimages&ailimit=100&aifrom=Panda&aiprop=url&format=xmlfm

and I know that basically this should show the usage:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=images&list=imageusage&iutitle=File:MY_IMAGE_NAME&format=xmlfm

Trying the above does not give me the result I need - I can see a list of images, but I cannot know if or where they are being used.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list=imageusage` does not show cross-wiki usage; you'll need `prop=globalusage` for that. Which is also conveniently a prop module, so it can be folded into the first query using `allimages` as a [generator](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators):

[action=query&generator=allimages&gailimit=100&gaifrom=Panda&prop=globalusage](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=allimages&gailimit=100&gaifrom=Panda&prop=globalusage&format=xmlfm)

(Omitted `prop=images` since it does not seem to have any useful purpose.)